# Repositioning nav buttons in p:wizard

Tags: jsf, button, primefaces, position, wizard

I wish to place the navigation buttons right under the step titles of the primefaces wizard component:

Since primefaces generates the both step tiles and content of the wizard together, I wasn't sure on how to insert an element (in this case, the nav buttons) between the two parts of the wizard component.
Anyway to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest solution is to set your wizard not to show the navigator buttons, then create a button of your own:

```
<p:wizard widgetVar="myWizard" showNavBar="false" ... >
<p:commandButton style="..." value="Back" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-w" 
    iconPos="right" type="button" onclick="myWizard.back();" />

<p:commandButton style="..." value="Next" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-e" 
    iconPos="left" type="button" onclick="myWizard.next();" />
```

---

You can also do this with jQuery and CSS, but in my opinion it is more difficult this way.

**Edit :-**

For Primefaces5.1 +

```
<p:commandButton style="..." value="Back" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-w" iconPos="right" onclick="PF('myWizard').back()" />
<p:commandButton style="..." value="Next" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-e" iconPos="left" onclick="PF('myWizard').next();" />
```

Comment: yea i have tried this, however how can I place these buttons right under the step titles?

Comment: Thanks! However I had to place these buttons right under each tab. Not directly under the wizard.

Comment: In PrimeFaces 5.1 the correct behavior for onclick is "PF('myWizard').back()". Otherwise myWizard is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is a bit outdated but maybe this will help someone.
In addition to **patstuart**'s answer (a great one that really helped me, +1) you can put these controls inside a div with CSS like this:

```
.formControlsBottom {  position: absolute !important;  bottom: 15px !important;  right: 15px !important;}
```

xhtml:

```
<div class="formControlsBottom">
    <p:commandButton value="Back" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-w" iconPos="right" type="button" onclick="PF('myWizard').back();"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Next" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-e" iconPos="left" type="button" onclick="PF('myWizard').next();"/>
</div>
```

I use it for positioning the buttons in the bottom of my dialogs.