# Primefaces dataTable single selection validation

Tags: validation, primefaces, datatable

I can validate a `p:selectOneMenu` like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="eventTimezoneDropdown"
        value="#{myBean.eventTimeZone}"
        required="true"
        requiredMessage="The TimeZone must be specified."
        effect="none">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.timeZoneItems}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Conceptually speaking, using a `p:dataTable` with single row selection will achieve the same goal - it allows you to select one row using a `selection` attribute instead of `value` attribute and using `value` attribute instead of `<f:selectItems>`.

```
<p:dataTable id="ActivitiesTable" var="row"
        value="#{myBean.rows}"
        selection="#{myBean.selectedRow}"
        rowKey="#{row.activityId}">
    <p:column selectionMode="single"/>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

However I don't see any validation options (e.g. a `required` attribute) on the `p:dataTable`.

Is there a way or workaround to have a required selection validation on a `p:dataTable` similar to the `required` attribute on `p:selectOneMenu`?

Environment: Primefaces 5.3, JSF 2.2.8-14, Tomcat 7.0.68.

Answer (score 1):

what i know in primefaces there are not this functionality in datatable, but you can play with your code,

i suggest that you can do the same event in your **ManagedBean**, so you can check if a row is selected or not, if yes then ok else you can create a simple message, that notifie the user that the selection of a row is required like that:

```
public void requiredSelect() {
    if (myObject == null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "My object is required!"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're suggesting to do the test after the update-model-value phase.  This would be easy enough to do in a submit, e.g. a `p:commandButton` with an actionListener.  However I'm in a `p:wizard` and I need it to happen when the "Next" button is clicked, which only does standard validation.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: did you tried to change the event of of Next button of wizard, you can check this exemple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995208/repositioning-nav-buttons-in-pwizard or this can help also: http://www.journaldev.com/3415/primefaces-wizard-component-example-tutorial

Comment: This gives me some success, but not complete.  The disadvantage is that adding a message in the `flowListener` is that the error message only shows up if all of the other validations pass.  This gives awkward behavior when the user gets a bunch of validation errors, then fixes them and submits, only to get an additional error message for the `dataTable`.

Comment: It's close, I may end up going with it if nothing better comes up.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to work around this issue is by using a hidden input field, bound to the same value which gets updated on row select.

```
<p:dataTable id="ActivitiesTable" var="row"
    value="#{myBean.rows}"
    selection="#{myBean.selectedRow}"
    rowKey="#{row.activityId}">
<p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio" update="@parent:hiddenTimezoneInput"
<p:column selectionMode="single"/>
...
</p:dataTable>

<h:inputHidden id="hiddenTimezoneInput" value="#{myBean.selectedRow}"
               required="true" requiredMessage="The TimeZone must be specified."/>
```

This way, you can add regular validators on the `inputHidden` (such as required) and have it processed on form submit.